# In Julia how do I get a list of global vars defined in a specific module?

Tags: julia

I've tried using varinfo(aModule) where aModule was incorporated with using.
But this just prints out

> name              size summary
> –––––––––––– ––––––––– –––––––
> aModule      104 bytes Module

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a module `M`

```
julia> module M
          a=5
          b=7
          c=[1,2,3]
       end
```

Than you can just do:

```
julia> names(M, all=true)
8-element Vector{Symbol}:
 Symbol("#eval")
 Symbol("#include")
 :M
 :a
 :b
 :c
 :eval
 :include
```

You can get the value of each field:

```
julia> getproperty(M, :c)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
```